Will my node relay a transaction if it is below minimum tx relay fee?
If I create a transaction which pays less fees than the minimum transaction relay fee of my full node, will my node relay the tx?

No, your node will only broadcast transactions that it accepts into its own mempool. If your transactions pays a lower feerate than your own node’s minimum transaction relay feerate ("minTxRelayFee"), your node will not accept your transaction and therefore not broadcast it either. If you configure your node to use a lower minTxRelayFee, your node will accept it. If any of your peer nodes have also configured a lower minTxRelayFee, it will forward it, but it will still likely not get mined unless it finds its way to a miner that also has set a lower minTxRelayFee, and that miner includes it in a block.
Given that there have been over 70 blocks worth of transactions bidding at least 1 sat/vB for the past year, it is unlikely for your transaction to get picked into a block any time soon, even if there were some miner that has their node configured with a lower minTxRelayFee.
